Why is Electron gain enthalpy opposite to Electron affinity
I've read in my textbook, that
$ΔegH=−A$
i.e. Electron gain enthalpy has the opposite sign of Electron affinity.
Why is that so? Since electron affinity is the energy released when an electron is added to an atom, and electron gain enthalpy is the measure of the ability of an atom to release energy when it gains electrons,
Why is $ΔegH=−A$? Shouldn't  $ΔegH$ and $A$ possess the same sign?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110667/relation-between-electron-gain-enthalpy-and-electron-affinity

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/183716/sign-conventions-for-electron-affinity-and-electron-gain-enthalpy

I is a matter of convention and definition. Enthalpy change is with respect to the product, the product loses energy to the environment. so energy production means that the product has less energy than the reactants. Electron affinity is with respect to the energy; Energy produces is positive. Energy gained is negative. I was an attempt to make things easy for students that sometimes complicates things when they think too hard about it.
